# Fail to passing value from MySQL to tidyr::spread

Tags: r, tidyr

here is my data received from lacal MySQL database, and trying to make it wide format,

```
   VT    Val   Unt   Nm    Tm
 <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 BW-201 11    Id    0B    79
2 BW-201 13    Bm    0B    79
3 BW-201  8    Id    0B    79
4 BW-201 10    Bm    0B    79
5 BW-201  4    Id    0B    79
6 BW-201  1    Bm    0B    79
```

with `con %>% tbl("ivt") %>% head()` it returns the data as above, but whe I try to spread it, it just went wrong

```
con %>% tbl("vt") %>% head() %>% tbl_df() %>% spread("Unt","Val")

Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (2, 4, 6), (1, 3, 5)
```

Whether i quote/unquote, or spread/spread_, just went wrong.
btw, if i don't use tbl_df(), it returns,

```
Error: Key column 'Unt' does not exist in input.
```

Pls advise, and many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no enough columns in the data to uniquely identify the `key:value` pairs. The solution is to add a col with row numbers. Then use `dplyr` to `filter` and `join` to remove NA.

```
df <- read.table(text="
VT    Val   Unt   Nm    Tm
1 BW-201 11    Id    0B    79
2 BW-201 13    Bm    0B    79
3 BW-201  8    Id    0B    79
4 BW-201 10    Bm    0B    79
5 BW-201  4    Id    0B    79
6 BW-201  1    Bm    0B    79", header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)

df$row <- 1:nrow(df) # add explicit row numbers

library(tidyr)
spread(df, key=Unt, value=Val)
    #       VT Nm Tm row Bm Id
    # 1 BW-201 0B 79   1 NA 11
    # 2 BW-201 0B 79   2 13 NA
    # 3 BW-201 0B 79   3 NA  8
    # 4 BW-201 0B 79   4 10 NA
    # 5 BW-201 0B 79   5 NA  4
    # 6 BW-201 0B 79   6  1 NA

library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% filter(Bm != "NA") %>% mutate(row = 1:n()) %>% select(-Id)
df2 <- df %>% filter(Id != "NA") %>% mutate(row = 1:n()) %>% select(-Bm)
df3 <- full_join(df1,df2)
#Joining, by = c("VT", "Nm", "Tm", "row")
df3
#       VT Nm Tm row Bm Id
# 1 BW-201 0B 79   1 13 11
# 2 BW-201 0B 79   2 10  8
# 3 BW-201 0B 79   3  1  4
```

Comment: Thanks @kathik, it really helps. I guess if I wanna  make the Bm, id at the same row (to plot), I might need to think how I can arrange the numeric index column.

Comment: @Grec001 I've added the code to remove NA. Pls accept the answer by clicking the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows and also upvote if this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry @karthik the core issue is how I can remotely handle the data from mysql with dplyr/tidyr, neverthe less your respondse is still valuable to me.